# Declaring a class template member that belongs to all specializations

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

What I'm looking for is a way to say: This is the same for all specializations:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
  using id_type = unsigned int; // this does not depend on T!
};

Foo::id_type theId; // Doesn't matter what the specialization is, id_type is always the same.
```

I want to access id_type without having to specify the specialization...

Comment: Why do you need the declare the using inside the struct itself?

Comment: *"This is the same for all specializations"* Nothing forbid user to add some specialization though....

Comment: @RoQuOTriX: For clarity. And I wanted to know whether there is the template equivalent of a static class member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have exactly what you are asking for. `Foo` is not a class. `Foo<T>` is a class, for any `T`.

You could have a non-template base that holds `id_type`

```
struct FooBase {
  using id_type = unsigned int;
};

template <typename T>
struct Foo : FooBase{};

FooBase::id_type theId;
```

You could provide a default parameter for `T`

```
template <typename T = struct FooPlaceholder>
struct Foo {
  using id_type = unsigned int; // this does not depend on T!
};

Foo<>::id_type theId;
```

However nothing stops me from writing an explicit specialisation of `Foo` that lacks (or redefines) `id_type`.

```
template <> struct Foo<MyType> { };    
template <> struct Foo<MyOtherType> { int id_type = 42; };
```

Comment: one can still specialize `Foo<S>` that does not inherit from `FooBase`

Comment: @Caleth: I'm going with your second idea: a dummy default type.

Comment: @Jarod42: Classes can be `final` to prevent a derived type. But there doesn't seem to be a way to prevent an explicit specialization that bypasses the original template. Seems like a gap in the language...

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `id_type` being a class (alias declaration) property, you could make it a stand-alone trait on a template template parameter:

```
#include <type_traits>

// Helper: compare with std::is_same but for
//         template template parameter type arguments.
template <template <typename> typename, template <typename> typename>
struct is_same_primary_template : std::false_type {};

template <template <typename> typename TT>
struct is_same_primary_template<TT, TT> : std::true_type {};

template <template <typename> typename TT, template <typename> typename UU>
constexpr bool is_same_primary_template_v{
    is_same_primary_template<TT, UU>::value};

template <typename T> struct Foo {};

template <template <typename> typename, typename Enable = void> struct id_type;

template <template <typename> typename TT>
struct id_type<TT, std::enable_if_t<is_same_primary_template_v<TT, Foo>>> {
  using type = int;
};

// ...

template <template <typename> typename TT>
using id_type_t = typename id_type<TT>::type;

int main() { id_type_t<Foo> theId; }
```

This approach has one drawback, though. As the trait is specialized over specific types it couples these types with the implementation of the trait (as you [want be very careful with the location of your specializations](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp#expl.spec-8.sentence-2), w.r.t. the location of the primary template).

> When writing a specialization, be careful about its location; or to make it compile will be such a trial as to kindle its self-immolation.

Answer (score 2):

Just an extension based on Caleth's answer and the comment ensuing from that.
You can kind of protect yourself from "bad" specializations of Foo like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// from Caleth

struct FooBase
{
    using id_type = unsigned int;
};

template <typename T>
struct Foo : FooBase 
{
};

FooBase::id_type theId{};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// specialization bypassing FooBase 

template<>
struct Foo<char>
{
};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// compile time check if someone mad a "bad" specialization, pre C++20

template<typename T>
void f(const Foo<T>& foo)
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<FooBase, Foo<T>>); 
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// C++20 concept to check for FooBase

template<typename T>
concept HasFooBase = std::is_base_of_v<FooBase, T>;

// only accepts types derived from FooBase
void g(const HasFooBase auto& foo)
{
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    Foo<int> foo;
    Foo<char> bar;

    f(foo);
    g(foo);

    f(bar); // won't compile, error C2607: static assertion failed
    g(bar); // won't compile, error C7602: 'g': the associated constraints are not satisfied

    return 0;
}
```